# How to Use Q to filter using String

Tags: django, python-3.x

Suppose I can  have these lists of strings(I already know how to get these list of strings from the user): `{"title, "year", "stars"}` and `{"title"}`. If I get the first one from the user, I want to filter the Movie objects such that it works like:
`Movie.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(year__icontains=query) |Q(stars__icontains=query))`. If i get the second one from the user, it is like 
`Movie.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)`

We have assured that the string in the list is a field of model.

Answer (score 2):

let say the name of the list you are getting is filterList. So you can try the  following

```
q_obj = Q()
for filter in filterList:
    q_obj |= Q(filter__icontains=query)

movies = Movie.objects.filter(q_obj)
```