# How to query the objects having all the given objects in Many To Many Field?

Tags: python, django

I was trying to find out one way where I can query all the objects of one table which are having the given objects as ManyToMany Field.

Please take below example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mail = models.EmailField()

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name="tags")
```

Here I want to fetch all the posts having both "python" and "django" in the tag list. I can do that at the python level by fetching all the Posts and then checking their tags.

is there any way we can directly fetch it from the DB? Using the DJango QuerySet.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try the following -

```
from django.db.models import Q

filteredPosts = Post.objects.filter(Q(tags__name='python')|Q(tags__name='django'))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry buddy, but it will also return the posts which are having only python or only django. I just want the posts which have both the python and django.

Comment: In that case, just replace the | between the Q with &. Q(tags__name='python')&Q(tags__name='django')

Comment: How can I make it dynamic, say I am getting the list of these tags name in API Input.

Comment: check out this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297083/12840065. Answered exactly same question  a while back

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Thanks, buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Post.objects.filter(id__in=list(Tag.objects.filter(name__in=['Python', 'Django']).values_list('posts', flat=True)))
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Q1 = Tag.objects.filter(name__exact='Django').values_list('posts', flat=True)
Q2 = Tag.objects.filter(name__exact='Python').values_list('posts', flat=True)
Post.objects.filter(id__in=list(set(Q2) & set(Q1)))
```

Comment: Yeah, this can give us the answer, but don't you think it will be quite slow?

Comment: Maby, but I don't have the same result when I use: Post.objects.filter(Q(tags__name='python')|Q(tags__name='django'))

Comment: Yes, that surely gives extra results. Anyhow, I have found my answer. Thank you so much for putting your efforts. :)

Comment: I don't mean extra results but I'm happy for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Q object you can query for `Post` objects which both have "python" **AND** "django" like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Post.objects.filter(Q(tags__name='python') & Q(tags__name='django'))
```

More information about how to make complex queries using the Q object in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: How can I make it dynamic, say I am getting the list of these tags name in API Input?